# Remove trailing slash and create query string with .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess file, I would like to remove the trailing slash from the URL without modifying the current setup for the query string.

I tried this in a two-step fashion, but it's not working as I expect:

```
# Remove trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [R=301]
# Create query string from canonical URL
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Cheers

Comment: What's not working ? Could you be more explicit ?

Comment: Instead of removing the trailing slash and sending the query string, the resulting request (and page) is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/dev/

## Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ $1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Cheers. I assumed I could use this locally in a subdirectory (eg, localhost/site/dev/) with RewriteBase (/site/dev/) - but it doesn't seem to affect the rule. Apologies for my noobery.